# PHP ssh working from command line, not working from web page

Tags: php, ssh

I am using PHP to ssh into a main computer and run a command. My code is posted below but I'm stuck having the following issue:

When I run this command from the Ubuntu command line it works flawlessly. However when I try and run it via the web page I believe the ssh commands are not running. Not sure if I am running into issues with permissions, or if I am running into issues with my actually ssh command in php. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $cmd = "ssh name@ip 'echo hello'";
    $var = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $var;
```

Comment: maybe the user that you use in command line and web server have different permissions?

Comment: As below, ssh is usually not allowed on any security-minded hosting company! ... It may allow direct, but not via web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `shell_exec` (which may be disabled for security reasons), look into using `libssh2`.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the user that the webserver runs as doesn't have your private key file in its ~/.ssh directory.